# Removing all records from a table that don't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with a lot (>20.000) records.
It's time to clean those up a little because queries are beginnen to take up a lot of recourses.
I have another (temporary) table with a **recent** records. All records in the first table that don't exist in the second one can go.
However, I need to keep the id's for the recent records because of some joins, so I can't just TRUNCATE and then copy the table.
Is there any way yo do this?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Do you want to remove entries from the Recent records, or from the bigger table?

Comment: Note that for a database, 20k rows is actually a *small* table. If you're getting performance problems there, you may wish to profile and look at relevant tables' indexes.

Comment: Hi, this is for a ZenCart webshop, and each time the site is loaded it tries to SELECT a lot.

Comment: I want to remove entries from the bigger table. The Recent table is actually a datafeed that I ``could`` put in a separate table to make the removing easier

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM old_table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table)
```

**Edit:**
`id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table)` is a lousy construction. If you have large tables and your server settings are tuned to low memory, you will execute this forever.

[@Piskvor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19746)'s answer is a longer, but a much better query, that will work best on low-memory setups. And when I say "low memory", I mean database servers that do not take up a full high-end computer, so pretty much any system that manages a small business website or stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I'd like to add something for future reference though: you should replace `id` with your unique value. For me it was the article name, since the record id's did not match in the two tables.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the `id`s of rows that don't have a corresponding row (matched by `recordid` column - yours may be different) in the other table:

```
SELECT t1.id 
    FROM firsttable t1
    LEFT JOIN secondtable t2
WHERE t1.recordid = t2.recordid
    AND t2.id IS NULL
```

That allows you to check that you're actually selecting the correct rows to delete. Then, plug it into a DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM firsttable WHERE firsttable.id IN (
    SELECT t1.id 
        FROM firsttable t1
        LEFT JOIN secondtable t2
    WHERE t1.recordid = t2.recordid
        AND t2.id IS NULL
)
```